# pressure required for displacing a single electron off a crystal

Tags: electricity, pressure, electrons, crystals, piezoelectric

I need to know this for my project- "power generation using the pressure applied on a keypad of a mobile electronic device". How much pressure does it take to displace a single electron off its crystal structure so that it is suitable for generating piezo-electricity?

Comment: I think this would be highly dependent on the specific crystal structure and how tightly the electron is bound

Comment: piezoelectricity is a collective phenomenn, so there is no way to calculate pressure for a single electron ( a quantum mechanical interaction, therefore probabilistic). This might help you in your project http://www.bigind.com.my/intranet/fckeditor/editor/images/smiley/66.pdf.

Comment: Thank You! Sir @anna v . ur attatched file is so informative.